# Cannot access a disposed object in ASP.NET Core background service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to figure out why my db context is being diposed of with the code below. I'm trying to update the status of the record throughout this processing stage, but I'm getting an exception when attempting to save the changes to the status field of htis entity.

It makes no difference if I use async or non-async methods on the .SaveChanges() or the .FirstOrDefault() calls.

This is registered to be run by an IHostedService

The IHostedService:

```
public class HostedDaemon : IHostedService
{
    private readonly ILogger<HostedDaemon> _logger;
    private Timer _queueTimer;
    private Timer _runTimer;
    private IServiceProvider Services { get; set; }

    public HostedDaemon(IServiceProvider services, ILogger<HostedDaemon> logger)
    {
        Services = services;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var queueAutoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        _logger.LogInformation("HostedDaemon Starting");
        _queueTimer = new Timer(QueueJobs, queueAutoEvent, TimeSpan.Zero,
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(900));
        _runTimer = new Timer(RunQueuedJobs, queueAutoEvent, TimeSpan.Zero,
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("HostedDaemon Stopping");
        _queueTimer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);
        _runTimer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _queueTimer?.Dispose();
        _runTimer?.Dispose();
    }

    private void QueueJobs(object stateInfo)
    {
        using (var scope = Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var autoEvent = (AutoResetEvent)stateInfo;
            var daemonProcessing = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDaemonService>();
            //daemonProcessing.QueueJob();
            //daemonProcessing.RunJob();
            autoEvent.Set();
        }
    }
    private void RunQueuedJobs(object stateInfo)
    {
        using (var scope = Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var autoEvent = (AutoResetEvent)stateInfo;
            var daemonProcessing = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDaemonService>();
            //daemonProcessing.QueueJob();
             daemonProcessing.RunJob(); 
            autoEvent.Set();
        }
    }
}
```

Background Service:

```
    public async Task RunJob()
    {
        try
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Starting transaction processing");
            //TODO: Hook up SP
            var nextQueuedJob = _context.Transaction
                .Where(x => x.TransactionStatusId == (int) TransactionStatus.Queued).OrderBy(x => x.QueuedTime)
                .Include(x => x.BrokerageData).FirstOrDefault();

            if (nextQueuedJob != null)
            {
                nextQueuedJob.TransactionStatusId = (int)TransactionStatus.ProcessingData;
                _context.Transaction.Update(nextQueuedJob);
                //await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                var brokerageData = nextQueuedJob.BrokerageData.FirstOrDefault();
                var order = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OrderShort>(brokerageData.BrokerageContent);

                var dynamicsSalesOrder = await CreateNewSalesOrderShort(order);
                var salesOrderLines = new List<SalesOrderLineShort>();
                foreach (var orderItem in order.Items)
                {
                    var unitPrice = (orderItem.SubTotal + orderItem.Tax)/orderItem.Quantity;
                    var salesOrderLine = new SalesOrderLineShort
                    {
                        ItemId = new Guid("42dd99ff-7133-41f7-88c5-81f922ef77dd"),
                        LineType = "Item",
                        Description = orderItem.ProductDescription,
                        UnitOfMeasureId = new Guid("cab0928b-e7af-4bd6-923f-3706b4761681"),
                        UnitPrice = unitPrice,
                        DiscountAmount = orderItem.CouponDiscountAmount,
                        Quantity = orderItem.Quantity,
                        TaxCode = "DEV"
                    };
                    salesOrderLines.Add(salesOrderLine);
                }
                nextQueuedJob.TransactionStatusId = (int)TransactionStatus.ProcessingComplete;
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                nextQueuedJob.TransactionStatusId = (int)TransactionStatus.ReadyForTransfer;
                //TOOO: hook into reconciliation tables to commit an update 
                nextQueuedJob.TransactionStatusId = (int)TransactionStatus.TransferringData;

                foreach (var salesOrderLine in salesOrderLines)
                {

                    await _requestClient.PostRequest(
                        $"https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v1.0/afff8eda-37c9-4c72-833b-a36dc6c8d5df/api/beta/companies/c7fdd45d-617d-47b3-adbe-7c0c69c21dd1/salesOrders/{dynamicsSalesOrder.Id}/salesOrderLines",
                        salesOrderLine);
                }

                nextQueuedJob.TransactionStatusId = (int)TransactionStatus.TransferComplete;

                nextQueuedJob.TransactionStatusId = (int)TransactionStatus.ReadyForValidation;
                nextQueuedJob.TransactionStatusId = (int)TransactionStatus.ValidatingOriginData;
                var query = new CrmQuery();
                query.UpdateOrderStatus(order.SalesOrderId, CrmQuery.OrderFIStatus.Completed,
                    order.FI_LastModified);
                nextQueuedJob.TransactionStatusId = (int)TransactionStatus.TransactionCompleted;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"exception occurred while running job.\n{e.InnerException}");
        }

    }
```

Exception:

```
Message "Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error
is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and then
later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your
application.
This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the
context in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you 
should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context 
instances.\r\nObject name: 'FisEntities'."  string
```

Startup Configuration:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        DynamicsAccountGuid = Configuration["Services:Dynamics:AccountGuid"];
        DynamicsCompany = Configuration["Services:Dynamics:Companies:Development"];
        DynamicsBasicAuth = Configuration["Services:Dynamics:BasicAuth"];
        ConnectionString = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:FIS_Local"];

        services.AddSingleton(Configuration);
        services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<FisEntities>(options => options.UseSqlServer(ConnectionString));

        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddHttpClient<IRequestClient, DynamicsClient>("dynamics", d =>
        {
            d.BaseAddress = new Uri($"https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v1.0/{DynamicsAccountGuid}/api/beta/companies/{DynamicsCompany}");
            d.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", DynamicsBasicAuth);
        });

        services.AddTransient<IQueueClient, CrmClient>();
        services.AddHostedService<HostedDaemon>();
        services.AddScoped<IDaemonService, TransactionService>();
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    }
```

Comment: When getting an exception please remember to post the actual error message into the question. From the looks of what you have above nothing should be disposing of the context

Comment: `I'm getting an exception`- Why did not add the exception message  to question? Please add the whole exception message to the question and the whole method including the method signature.

Comment: Are you by chance using some old/funky MySQL provider from Oracle for it?

Comment: @Gibbon it's a generic object disposed exception, but I've added the text from it regardless.

Comment: @TanvirArjel added, but it's generic

Comment: @Tseng No, it's SqlServer

Comment: @Propagating Add the `Startup.ConfigureServices` method code the question.

Comment: @TanvirArjel I've added it. I should note that this is only occuring in the method pasted above, and that all of the other entity framework calls in this method are successfully completing.

Comment: Please add your method signature..I suspect problen is there..

Comment: Method signature means method name, return type etc. Better add full method code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190138/discussion-between-propagating-and-tanvirarjel).

Comment: @Propagating Please edit your question to include a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others, that will throw the exception. Also, add the full exception message including the full stack trace so we can check where the exception come from.

Comment: @Progman I've added more, but I'm not sure what more I can add beyond those areas.

Comment: @Propagating The code you have added is not complete. Please add the full source codes of your classes you have. We don't even see the `TransactionService` class, where the error occured.

Comment: @Progman Transaction Service is the background service I posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `RunQueuedJobs` method in `HostedDaemon` class, replace `daemonProcessing.RunJob();` with `daemonProcessing.RunJob().Wait();` as follows:

```
private void RunQueuedJobs(object stateInfo)
{
    using (var scope = Services.CreateScope())
    {
        var autoEvent = (AutoResetEvent)stateInfo;
        var daemonProcessing = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDaemonService>();
        //daemonProcessing.QueueJob();
         daemonProcessing.RunJob().Wait(); // <-- Here it is
        autoEvent.Set();
    }
}
```

Now it should work properly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that helped! Can you explain why exactly that is necessary?